# how dynamically update doc terms by using another analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch

One document has been segmented by analyzer: `ik_smart`(specified in _mapping) to  `A BC D`, but I want to change the generated terms by using another analyzer: `ik_max_word` could I reindex the doc by another analyzer dynamically?

Supplement:
I do not want to assign a new analyzer to the field, I just want to change the specific doc's terms to [AB C D]

Comment: Are you trying to assign a new analyzer  to a field which already has one?

Comment: @AssaelAzran No I just want to change this specific doc's terms to [AB C D]

Comment: See my answer. hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @AssaelAzran Thanks! but it seems not so simple, because I want to update doc _termvectors

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add an analyzer in settings first, then add mappings using this analyzer and if required reindex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but you will need to re-index your content otherwise your searches won't work as expected.

**Step-by-step instructions**

1. Configure your analyzer in the settings of your index (if it's a custom analyzer)
2. Close your index
3. Adjust your mapping by specifying the field's `analyzer` and if required also the `search_analyzer`
4. Re-open your index
5. Execute `POST <my index>/_update_by_query`

Comment: What if **ik_smart**  has already been assign to "data" field for example, how would you assign a new analyzer to "data" without deleting the index?

Comment: The Analyzer determines which tokens get produced. You cannot change the tokens afterwords, unless re-indexing the document/field using the updated/changed Analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your last update you can use the `update` api.

[Update Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html)

Run the following (**1 is your doc id**):

```
POST my_index/_update/1
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.yourfield= params.value",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "value" : "[AB C D]"
        }
    }
}
```